# Why is my loader destroyed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loader

I have a Fragment which uses a Loader. The Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks. In the `onCreate()` of the fragment I do a `setRetainInstance(true)` so that the Fragment is not destroyed across configuration changes like orientation change. This works as expected and the `onDestroy()` for the fragment is not called. However, my loader is destroyed when I rotate the device. Each time I rotate the device a new Loader is created. I checked the memory dump and verified this.

1. Why is this happening
2. How can I avoid this ?

**EDIT**: To avoid confusion : The local variable loader is not relevant here. It is just to check if my previously created loader exists or not. Even with the updated code below (removed the local variable), the loader is destroyed.

Here is some relevant code:

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object> {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true); //Don't destroy fragment across orientation change
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated, myTid : " + android.os.Process.myTid());

        mLoaderManager = getLoaderManager();
        mLoaderManager.initLoader(MY_LOADER, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Object> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateLoader, myTid : " + android.os.Process.myTid());
        return new MyLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }

   @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Object> objectLoader) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLoaderReset, myTid : " + android.os.Process.myTid());

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mTxtSomeTxt != null) {
                    mTxtSomeTxt.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried making your local `Loader` variable (in `onActivityCreated()`) a class member? It may get garbage collected on configuration changes because nothing is referencing it anymore.

Comment: In onActivityCreated() I'm just testing if a loader exists by querying the LoaderManager. I don't think making this variable a class member is related.

Comment: How do you see that it gets reset?

Comment: The onReset for the loader gets called. Also, a new object is created. I'm tracking the object ID in the loader.

Comment: Can you update your question to have the complete (minimal if you can) activity including the loader? Are you using a custom loader or CursorLoader?

Comment: why do you need the loader preserved across activity lifecycles? Why not make it a singleton?

Comment: Don't use singletons for these things on Android, they are error prone. Instead use loaders properly, they were created to solve these kinds of problems.

Comment: @alexanderblom please add an example or link. Elaboration would be helpful for all.

Comment: I'm using a custom loader. I do not have anything special in the activity. It just has a setContentView with the layout that contains the above fragment. According to the docs, if you call setRetainInstance(true), the fragment will not be destroyed on a device rotation however the view will be destroyed and recreated. However, this should not destroy the loader. So, either the docs are wrong or I don't get it ! Reto mentioned in the dev hangout that setRetainInstance is designed for fragments without a UI. May be that is what is affecting.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Perhaps it is related to reported bug by CommonsWare. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20791&can=5&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars My loader also being destroyed, when I pop up a new activity over the old activity, perform rotation, close the new actibvity. the loader in old activity will be destroyed and re-created.

Comment: Another place where this bug is reported. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/DbKL6PVyhLI

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late to the party...

For retained fragments you need to save the loader returned from initLoader(...) and then when a configuration change occurs return the original loader.

```java
private Loader<Object> myLoader;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated, myTid : " + android.os.Process.myTid());

    mLoaderManager = getLoaderManager();
    myLoader = mLoaderManager.initLoader(MY_LOADER, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<Object> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateLoader, myTid : " + android.os.Process.myTid());

    // Handle loader creation on retrained fragments
    if (myLoader != null)  {
        return myLoader;
    }

    return new MyLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
}
```